# Burned TrentaOS ISO to USB Stick: Not detected in UEFI

Tags: uefi, iso-image, burning, liveusb

Well, I decided to try out the [TrentaOS](http://trentaos.org/about.html) distribution and downloaded their ISO image from sourceforge. First, because I was on Windows, I tried to burn that image to my USB stick with Rufus, but when I got to the boot menu, there was no entry to boot from my stick.
Secondly, I tried it via the dd command on linux and the SUSE Image Writer, which led sadly to the same result (yeah I'm pretty sure, that I used dd correctly, burned a lot of images successfully with that in the past).
After all that, I think there is something wrong with the TrentaOS Alpha 3 image. 
Is it possible that they're not supporting UEFI yet (and my stick will be only detected if I enable legacy support) ?

Comment: Have you checked that booting from USB is enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: Yeah, I've got a lenovo notebook and the option called "USB Boot" is enabled. Well, of course it had to, because I booted from USB sticks several times before.

Comment: You didn't mention it so that's definitely the first question.  Have you tried booting to this USB on another computer?

Comment: Well, currently I don't have access to another computer to boot from, so I can't check that. And that doesn't matter cuz I want to boot from the USB stick on my laptop.

Comment: It matters for the fact that we could rule out whether or not the TrentaOS image you have on the USB is the problem or it's your computer.

Comment: Have you tried legacy support to see if it will boot? If it works then no UEFI support yet.

Comment: @Cand3r Well, tried it on my desktop PC (which has UEFI, too) and surprisingly it works there. So there has to be UEFI support. That suprises me a bit, because I booted from a lot of other linux distros on my notebook.

Comment: Try a different port would by next guess.  I struggled with one USB port formatting a HD and everything worked when I used a different port.  Had more dead/dying USB ports than computers...

Comment: I already used my USB2 Port instead my USB3 port but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Hmm, if it works on the other and you've booted from other USB's I'm not sure.  Maybe try a BIOS update but that seems like overkill...

Comment: And I have no idea how to udpate my bios on my lenovo notebook with OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.

Comment: it would depend on whether or not the manufacturer has bootable update, doesn't matter what OS you're running

Comment: Yeah, I know that, just can't find through the search engine a appropriate strike for Lenovo Ideadpas. Just wonder why this image causes issues with booting (just burned for testing reasons kubuntu and it worked flawlessly)

Comment: The fact that it booted on another EFI-based computer is ***not*** necessarily diagnostic. That computer might have had its CSM enabled, meaning it might have booted in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. There could also be Secure Boot issues. Check the USB drive. To be bootable in EFI mode, there must be a FAT filesystem with a file called `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` (assuming a 64-bit EFI).

Comment: The image only be booted from when I activated legacy support in my laptops UEFI, so I assume there is no EFI support yet. Secure Boot is disabled on my notebook, that can not be the reason. I think the ISO has no EFI support. When I choose the GPT partition scheme under Rufus for my usb stick and choose the trentaos it says in an error message that the ISO image is not EFI-bootable.